# .htaccess RewriteRule change underscore to dash

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a ReWrite rule in my .htaccess file right now:

```
RewriteRule ^item/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?/?$ static/items.php?a=$1&b=$2 [NC,L]
```

It will pick any items that have an underscore:

```
item/new_item/new_order
```

However, I need to change from underscore to dashes to make it:

```
item/new-item/new-order
```

If I simply make a change in RewriteRule string it breaks it. Not sure how to fix that.

```
RewriteRule ^item/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?$ static/items.php?a=$1&b=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I am assuming you don't want a rule that goes from `item/new_item/new_order` to `item/new-item/new-order`, but a rule that matches the latter one? The wording in your question is confusing me.

Comment: Yes, I want to change it to "-". Currently it is "_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *fairly tricky stuff* but can be done using following `Rewrite` rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# first replace each _ by - recursively
RewriteRule ^(item)/([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1/$2-$3 [L,NC]

# now usual stuff to forward request to static/item.php
RewriteRule ^(item)/([^_/]*)/?([^_/]*)/?$ static/$1.php?a=$2&b=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: This looks interesting, but won't this change my previous approach where the $1 and $2 were optional? All I need to change in my current string is the wat the words are connected, from underscore to dash.

Comment: Do you want to make both `$1` and `$2` optional?

Comment: Made some minor edit, it should work by making both `$1 and $2 optional`